# ps2pdf (ghostscript) crops image

Tags: ghostscript

While trying to create a pdf from ps2pdf command on SUSE v12 (tried on centos 7 too), the resulting image is cropped. Command -

```
convert atms_npp.omgnbc_region4_fr2.png file.ps
ps2pdf file.ps file.pdf
```

If convert command is used, the resulting file is correct. -

```
 ps2pdf file.ps file_conv.pdf
```

Do i need to provide additional flags to ps2pdf command ?. I would like to avoid hardcoding resolution with ps2pdf (example: -sPAPERSIZE=) as it is possible that the input png have different resolution.

Please let me know if i can provide more information on this issue.

Here are relevant files - https://bitbucket.org/puneet336/ps2pdf/src/master/.

Comment: There's no possible way anyone can help you with this problem without seeing the original PostScript file. It would probably also be a decent idea to mention the operating system, and the version of Ghostscript you are using, as well as any back channel outptu from Ghostscript.

Comment: Thanks & Sorry.
i had uploaded files on bitbucket, forgot to share the link.
will update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PostScript program doesn't request a media size. In the absence of a media size request Ghostscript uses its default, the exact value of which which depends on the operating system and the presence or not of libpaper.

Adding -sPAPERSIZE does not 'hardcode the resolution' it simply sets the media size. You're going to have to use that, or the DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS/DEVIEHEIGHTPOINTS settings to tell Ghostscript that you want to use some size other than the default.

Although it doesn't affect this file, you are also using an old version of Ghostscript, 9.15. The current version is 9.23 and will be superseded by 9.24 in about a month. Your version is 3 years old.

Comment: I tried running  ---    ps2pdf -sDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1000 -sDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=600 file.ps file.pdf.  


-- I got following error:

Unrecoverable error: typecheck in .putdeviceprops
Unrecoverable error: undefinedfilename in setpagedevice
Operand stack:
    true  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--


do i need to provide more flags (to use width/height points)?

Comment: Those should be -d, not -s

Comment: Thanks , 
"-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1100 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=850" seems best .
As i am working with shell scripts, I can pull out  values for  DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS & DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS  via grep utility from line "%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 1100 850" of .ps file.   It could be great if ps2pdf could pick this up automatically (one of the default setting/preference like .vimrc ?).

Comment: You can change the script yourself, we won't. The '%' character introduces a comment in PostScript, which is why the interpreter ignores it. If the program was an **E** PS, (Encapsulated PostScript) rather than plain PostScript program you could use -dEPSCrop to get Ghostscript to use the BoundingBox comments. PostScript programs are expected to request the media size thwy want. You should take this up with the people behind the application producing the PostScript, or switch to EPS if the application supports that.